# How to change the background color of terminal emulator background?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How to change the dark purple color of terminal emulator background?
And can we place any image or photo instead of that purple color.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Right click on terminal screen, then "Profiles" - "Profile preferences" - "color" - "background color".

Have fun :)

Edit:
If you want a picuture, go to "Profiles" - "Profile preferences" - "Background" - "Background image" :)

Comment: ohh, its so easy, thank you. Now I can work on lighter background in terminal.

Comment: @Vlad how can you achieve this via commandline.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Edit / Preferences.
Make sure to uncheck *Use colors from system theme*,
than you can change the schemes

[image]