# How to change the background color on a Ubuntu terminal in WSL?

Tags: command-line, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS from the Windows Store and I want to change the background colour of the terminal from black to white. Is this possible?

Comment: Ubuntu from the Windows Store? I am not sure we support this kind of heresy here.
Anyway, check my answer.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Your question already has an accepted answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/278493/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-terminal-emulator-background

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the background color of terminal emulator background?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278493/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-terminal-emulator-background)

Comment: ... more likely [I want to permanently change the background color to white and the text color to black in Command Prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/581924/i-want-to-permanently-change-the-background-color-to-white-and-the-text-color-to) in the case of WSL

Answer (score 1):

- Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
- click *Edit* > *Options* in Menubar
- click panel *Colors*
- change colors
- click *Close*

Changes should be permanent for all terminals.